# When using settings file, updating app.config directly yields no results

Tags: c#, .net, windows-console

I am using a settings file (*.settings)  in one of my console application projects. The problem is that if I directly update, the app.config generated by the settings file, the changes do not take effect. For any change in configuration, I need to open the code and update the settings file. Is this the expected behavior?

Update: I took Simon's advice and dropped the settings file altogether. Now I just use a config file in the project that has the entry point to the application. Things are a lot simpler now.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you changed and what's not working as expected?

Comment: If you're using a settings file why are you changing the keys/values directly in the app.config?

Comment: i find the designer experience of settings files to be unnecessarily complex. just place your config settings directly in the app.config

Comment: I think app.config is generated every time from settings file every time you run the application.